# multiple lists from csv dictreader

Tags: python, csv

I have a simple CSV file with two keys, "Title" and "Author" with a bunch of data.

I want to make a list of the titles, and then a list of the authors. My code is as below. It prints the title_list but no the author_list, why?

````py
import csv

with open("books.csv", encoding="utf-8-sig") as books_csv:
    books_reader = csv.DictReader(books_csv)
    title_list = [book["Title"] for book in books_reader]
    author_list = [book["Author"] for book in books_reader]

    print(title_list)
    print(author_list)```
````

Comment: files get read 1x only. so the 2nd time you try to iterate over `books_reader` there's nothing to iterate over. you should not iterate over that 2x anyway. can you think of a way to iterate 1x over `books_reader` and populate both lists? it might involve a traditional `for` loop instead of list-comps.

Comment: Please add an example of your csv that you are trying to parse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`books_reader` is an [iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader). When you use list-comprehension to define `title_list` you exhaust the iterator leaving `books_reader` empty. That is why when you go to define `author_list` it returns nothing. Using list-comprehension for this problem is not the correct solution. You are probably looking for the following:

```
import csv

title_list = []
author_list = []
with open("books.csv", encoding="utf-8-sig") as books_csv:
    books_reader = csv.DictReader(books_csv)
    for book in books_reader:
        title_list.append(book["Title"])
        author_list.append(book["Author"])
```